# running a container with runAsNonRoot and add capabilities

Tags: linux, kubernetes, linux-capabilities

I was trying to run my pod as non root and also grant it some [capabilities](https://linux.die.net/man/7/capabilities).
This is my config:

```yaml
 containers:
    - name: container-name
        securityContext:
          capabilities:
            add: ["SETUID", "SYS_TIME"]
          readOnlyRootFilesystem: true
          runAsNonRoot: true
          runAsUser: 1001
```

when I deploy my pod and connect to it I run `ps aux` and see:

```
PID   USER     TIME  COMMAND
    1 root      0:32 node bla.js
  205 root      0:00 /bin/bash
  212 root      0:00 ps aux
```

I then do `cat /proc/1/status` and see:

```
CapPrm: 0000000000000000
CapEff: 0000000000000000
```

Which means I have no capabilities for this container's process.
The thing is that if I remove the `runAsNonRoot: true` flag from the `securityContext` I can see I **do** have multiple capabilities.
Is there a way to run a pod as a non-root and still add some capabilities?

Comment: `SETUID` seems like an odd one to combine with `runAsNonRoot` as it allows the process to become root.

Comment: What are `CapBnd` and `CapInh` in your setup? If they are both zero, then no capabilities will be accessible to the code.

Comment: @eladm26, was the answer useful?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the expected behavior. The capabilities are meant to divide the privileges traditionally associated with superuser (root) into distinct units; a non-root user cannot enable/disable such capabilities, that could create a security breach.

The `capabilities` feature in the `SecurityContext` key is designed to manage (either to limit or to expand) the Linux capabilities for the container's context; in a pod run as a root this means that the capabilities are inherited by the processes since these are owned by the root user; however, if the pod is run as a non-root user, it does not matter if the context has those capabilities enabled because the Linux Kernel will not allow a non-root user to set capabilities to a process.

This point can be illustrated very easily. If you run your container with the  key `runAsNonRoot` set to `true` and add the capabilities as you did in the manifest shared, and then you exec into the Pod, you should be able to see those capabilities added to the context with the command:

```
$ capsh --print
Current: = cap_chown,cap_dac_override,cap_fowner,cap_fsetid,cap_kill,cap_setgid,cap_setuid,cap_setpcap,cap_net_bind_service,cap_net_raw,cap_sys_chroot,cap_sys_time,cap_mknod,cap_audit_write,cap_setfcap+i
Bounding set =cap_chown,cap_dac_override,cap_fowner,cap_fsetid,cap_kill,cap_setgid,cap_setuid,cap_setpcap,cap_net_bind_service,cap_net_raw,cap_sys_chroot,cap_sys_time,cap_mknod,cap_audit_write,cap_setfcap
```

But you will see the `CapPrm` or `CapEff` set to x0 in any process run by the user 1001:

```
$ ps aux
USER         PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
1001           1  0.0  0.0   4340   760 ?        Ss   14:57   0:00 /bin/sh -c node server.js
1001           7  0.0  0.5 772128 22376 ?        Sl   14:57   0:00 node server.js
1001          21  0.0  0.0   4340   720 pts/0    Ss   14:59   0:00 sh
1001          28  0.0  0.0  17504  2096 pts/0    R+   15:02   0:00 ps aux
$ grep Cap proc/1/status
CapInh: 00000000aa0425fb
CapPrm: 0000000000000000
CapEff: 0000000000000000
CapBnd: 00000000aa0425fb
CapAmb: 0000000000000000
```

Comment: If I can only add capabilities to the root user, but the root user already has all the root user capabilities, what is the point?  If I wanted to run a nodejs container as non root but on port 80, how would I add CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE?

Comment: @Marvin You can also drop capabilities from a root user, making for a smaller attack surface if your process running as root is compromised.